# SQL normalization

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, normalization

right now, i have a table:

```
Id  -  CollegeName   -   CourseName
```

this table is not normalized so i have many Courses for every 1 College
I need to normalize this into two tables:

```
Colleges:  CollegeID  -  CollegeName  
Courses:   CourseID  - CollegeID  - CourseName
```

Is there an easy way to do this?
Thank you

Comment: I suppose with normalized you mean 3rd normal form, but your example code doesn't violate that.  There are no fields that depend only on CollegeName.  If there was also a CollegeMailingAddres column, that would violate 3NF.

Comment: @Andomar True but there are plenty of reasons why this refactoring is still beneficial.

Comment: @Martin: Normalizing is notorious for adding complexity. A form to enter a new course will now have to touch two tables instead of one.  Doesn't sound too bad, but it really adds up.

Comment: @Andomar - In order to get the maximum rows on the page I'd rather repeat an `int` multiple times than an `nvarchar(50)` or whatever. Additionally what about the complexity if a college changes its name or the need to prevent multiple slight differences in its name creeping in?

Comment: thanx for the help, everyone. Here, wasn't even a question of what was more correct, i really needed this in this  form :)

Comment: @Andomar: "Normalizing is notorious for adding complexity" -- Normalization is famous for removing anomalies. Denormalization should only be considered as a last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the 2 new tables with Colleges.CollegeID and Courses.CourseID as auto numbered fields, you can go with :

```
INSERT INTO Colleges (CollegeName)
  SELECT DISTINCT CollegeName 
    FROM OLdTable ;

INSERT INTO Courses (CollegeID, CourseName)
  SELECT Colleges.CollegeID, OldTable.CourseName 
    FROM OldTable
      JOIN Colleges
        ON OldTable.CollegeName = Colleges.CollegeName ;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.College
(
  CollegeId     int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  CollegeName   nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.Course
(
  CourseId      int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  CollegeId     int NOT NULL,
  CourseName    nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE dbo.Course
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Course_College FOREIGN KEY (CollegeId)
  REFERENCES dbo.College (CollegeId)

--- add colleges
INSERT INTO dbo.College (CollegeName)
SELECT DISTINCT CollegeName FROM SourceTable

--- add courses
INSERT INTO dbo.Course (CollegeId, CourseName)
SELECT
  College.CollegeId,
  SourceTable.CourseName
FROM
  SourceTable
INNER JOIN
  dbo.College ON SourceTable.CollegeName = College.CollegeName
```

Comment: thank you anyway, but i had to give the ansery to ypercube, he was the first

Answer (score 1):

I agreed with @Andomar's first comment: remove the seemingly redundant `Id` column and your `CollegeName, CourseName` table is already in 5NF.

What I suspect you need is a further table to give courses attributes so that you can model the fact that, say, Durham University's B.Sc. in Computing Science is comparable with Harvard's A.B. in Computer Science (via attributes 'computing major', 'undergraduate', 'country=US, 'country=UK', etc).

Comment: cheers, really, but this was a very specific task i needed to do :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

Create a College table with a college_id (primary key) column, and a college_name column which is used as a unique index column.

Just refer to the college_id column, not college_name, in the Course table.

Comment: yes, but this table is thousands of rows long. I am looking for a query to do this the easy way, i know what to do, just not how to do it